# Java Eclipse JRebel Mercurial Stop tracking

Tags: java, eclipse, mercurial, atlassian-sourcetree, jrebel

Hello i am trying JRebel as evaluation is working now but as we use `mercurial and source tree` i see the mark some files as changed `after adding JRebel nature` i want this files not send to the server when i commit the code... Because they do not use JRebel and i dont want to change their Eclipse configuration...

Files Marked as Changed it

[image: Files Marked as Changed it]

I can see the options right clicking on it...

[image: Options]

As i am not good handling mercurial i would like this files not send to the server when commiting but i dont know if this is possible and if so which is the best approach [remove,Stop tracking,Discard].

Thanks a lot..

Best regards from Venezuela

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should just add the .metadata folder to your mercurial ignore list.

If you've already committed the file to your repo, then you need to do something like this:

`hg remove -Af .project`

Stop tracking from the context menu I think does the same thing.